# How to plot 2 arrays in modelica?

Tags: modelica

I mean a plot that's made with points such as **1st element of array A and 1st element of array B** and so on.

Comment: What tool are you suing? OpenModelica? Dymola? Maybe plotting is easier with Python and the DyMat package: https://bitbucket.org/jraedler/dymat

Comment: I am using OMEdit. I need to do plotting in this one for my project. There's a command "quiver" but i don't understand how to use it!